Laravel - Get count of each courses from foreach loop
I have class schedule model, and course model in laravel. I am trying to get list of course schedule count, but when running foreach loop, I am getting the list of items, but i want to get the number of schedules for course
Here is my code in view blade.
@foreach ($singledegreesection->classschedule as $schedule)
    {{ $schedule->ccourse->course->course_title }} <br>
@endforeach

I am getting the result as below
computer networks

cryptography and cyber security

embedded systems and iot

computer networks

I want to print the result as below
computer networks - 2

cryptography and cyber security - 1

embedded systems and iot - 1


You could use the collection's groupBy method with a Closure.
@php
$grouped = $singledegreesection
    ->classschedule
    ->groupBy(fn ($schedule) => $schedule->ccourse->course->course_title)
@endphp
@foreach ($grouped as $title => $group)
    {{ $title }} - {{ $group->count() }}<br>
@endforeach


Thank you !! it works as expected, appreciated..
